# Ubuntu 17.10 not detecting bluetooth mouse

Tags: bluetooth, 17.10

My Logitech bluetooth mouse worked in 17.04 until I did a fresh install of 17.10 on my Dell Inspiron, now it doesn't see it. Bluetooth is on and sees my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem after upgrade to 17.10.
For my intel bluetooth adapter disabling bt_coex_active solved it.

It uses iwlwifi so adding the text above in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf disables it, you can do it in one line:

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0"|sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

then you should restart your computer or you can reload your wifi modules. Again in one line:

```
sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlmvm
```

Comment: Where in the file should this be added?

Comment: The file does not need to be edited directly, the echo command will append the directive to the file.

Comment: I needed to restart the computer a second time after the last command for it to work.