# Bluetooth not working on fresh Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 17.10

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 and tested my Bluetooth settings. I have two Logitech X100 Bluetooth speakers. `hciconfig -a` returns this when I turned on my bluetooth:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: E4:A7:A0:56:DC:A8  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
        RX bytes:15707 acl:0 sco:0 events:2449 errors:0
        TX bytes:601048 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2441 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
        Name: 'Bluemoon Universal Bluetooth Host Controller'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
        LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Now the first issue was, that when I connect to the speakers, it disconnects after a few seconds and it disappears in the audio settings. More strange, the Bluetooth speakers and Ubuntu are still paired (the LED is still on (not blinking) and Ubuntu shows me its connected).
In Ubuntu I cannot disconnect the speakers anymore, because I got a timeout for this action (seen in the sys-logs).

So I tried installing Blueman, and it didn't help, so I uninstalled it again. Now I cannot find the first Bluetooth box anymore (it never appears in the scan-list) and I cannot connect to the second speakers (at least, Ubuntu bluetooth can find them). More strange, Ubuntu thinks it connects and pairs with the 2nd speakers, but the speaker itself shows me, nothing happened.

And again, disconnect won't work because Ubuntu receives a timeout.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/966931/732822

Comment: Indeed, that solved it o.O Thank you very much!