# MX Anywhere not detected in 17.10

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

My computer does not detect my MX Anywhere mouse (bluetooth) in Ubuntu 17.10. I tried the solution in [Ubuntu 17.10 not detecting bluetooth mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966734/ubuntu-17-10-not-detecting-bluetooth-mouse) but couldn't make it work. Is there anything else I can try? My smartphone and headphones are detected .

Edit:

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [103c:161c]  
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e  
    Kernel modules: e1000e  
    --  
25:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)  
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]  
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth Combo  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2805 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep Blue`:

```
[   13.278105] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22  
[   13.278124] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized  
[   13.278127] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized  
[   13.278129] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized  
[   13.278135] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized  
[   25.231678] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
[   25.231679] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[   25.231682] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[   61.677491] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized  
[   61.677512] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized  
[   61.677525] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: It's an anywhere 2 if that makes any difference.

Comment: It does indeed. It's a hp elitebook 8460p. So far I have managed to find out that it has bluetooth 2.1. I'm trying to find more specific info, but is this relevant?

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. I simply meant to ask if the information I provided was relevant since I missed the example link, it appeared on a new line on my screen. Anyway, I will edit the question.

Comment: It seems some answers were deleted. Anything wrong?