# Ubuntu 20.04 can't detect bluetooth mouse

Tags: 20.04, mouse, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse which I can't get to work. When I put the mouse in pairing mode, the bluetooth settings menu doesn't show it. However, it does detect other devices like my phone.

I tried:

- [The answer in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966734/ubuntu-17-10-not-detecting-bluetooth-mouse) in short: setting bt_coex_active=0 in iwlwifi config
- bluetoothctl with 'scan on' only shows the same phone but no mouse
- Blueman interface
- Pairing my mouse to Windows, works

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I copy with sudo, folder from old HDD (18.04) that was working fine on to the new SSD (20.04)
Re-boot and oh miracle mouse appears on the list and working fine !
/var/lib/bluetooth/mac_your_bt/mac_your_mouse